# brew : install new option to existing formula

Tags: opencv, homebrew, opencv3.0

I would like to install a new option to an existing installed formula, i.e I already installed the formula like this

```
brew install opencv3 --with-qt --with-java --with-ffmpeg
```

but now I wan't to have

```
brew install opencv3 --with-qt --with-java --with-ffmpeg --with-python3
```

but doing this gives me the error "opencv3 is already installed" and same thing for an upgrade attempt.

Does somebody know how to do it without re-installing everything ?

Comment: `brew reinstall opencv3 --with-qt --with-java --with-ffmpeg --with-python3` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

`brew reinstall opencv3 --with-qt --with-java --with-ffmpeg --with-python3`

See here https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/12511